# webpack not copying images

Tags: javascript, webpack

I trying to import local package, that already bundled in webpack. When I build an app everything looks good, except webpack not copying images, fonts, etc. from that internal package. Any ideas what's going wrong?

When I try to reference my custom library, that is already bundled:

```
- dist
-- asdfjlsjdflasdjflsdaf.ttf
-- sdjflsjdfasjdflsjdfsd.eot
-- mylibrary.js
```

only mylibrary.js is copied. So parent app looks like:

```
- dist
-- mylibrary.js
-- parentapp.js
- packages
-- mylibrary
--- src...
--- dist...
```

Problem could be solved:

1. by increasing the loader limit and everything that converted to
   base64 and included in mylibrary.js is available in my parent app
2. copy plugin, which copy fonts from mylibrary, but this solution looks ugly, since everyone who using mylibrary should care about copying fonts, images, etc.

Comment: Can you please share your webpack config? Without it no one will be able to answer it.

Comment: Probably you miss a file extractor? Try comparing it with the generated webpack config of an ejected `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for copying images and fonts using webpack would be the use of GlobCopyWebpackPlugin.

How it works (I am not quite sure how your current webpack configuration looks like) but let`s go with a blank slate and see if this might help you. So, you can keep separate webpack files for different environments - say for now a prod and dev. Once you have created webpack.config.dev.js, inside the "plugins" property you can use GlobCopyWebpackPlugin. It would look something like below:

```
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
        "patterns": [
            "Assets"
        ],
        "globOptions": {
            "cwd": path.join(process.cwd(), "src"),
            "dot": true,
            "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
        }
    }),
```

"Assets" is the folder where you have kept fonts, icons, multimedia etc.

And then you can configure your tasks inside package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "npm run -s generatelocalefiles && node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack.config.dev.js --port=4300",
    }
```

And the folder structure looks like this (just in case you are wondering)

```
-src
  -app
  -assets
-package.json
-webpack.config.dev.js
-webpack.config.prod.js
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, however when someone including library he usually not care about images and fonts in that library, let's say I'm using https://github.com/palantir/blueprint. So I don't have to copy anything from blueprint, just import and use. Webpack doing this job.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand is to see how webpack takes care of images, fonts etc.

[Here](https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap) is a module that uses bootstrap and has the required concepts in action.

The index.html uses bootstrap styles **and** one glyph as well. The glyph (and bootstrap in all) uses one image from bootstrap binaries.

After you build the module, you can compare the paths of the image in original bootstrap binary (i.e. `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`) and the bundled output file (i.e. `dist/bundle.js`). You can search for `glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg` in those files.

The webpack simply

1. Copies images/fonts to your configured (in loader config) output folders
2. Updates those resource paths in the bundled output files (i.e. js, css etc)

(1) above need to be configured by you via a loader for ex. (2) will be automatically taken care by webpack provided the `module.rules` in webpack config are working properly for the images/fonts.

Hope that makes things a bit clear.

Comment: Sounds good, it works well for the library that uses bootstrap. All images/fonts are copied to output folder. But in case of usage of library that uses bootstrap things are different.

Comment: @AlexanderVinober Given that webpack is a module bundler, it should be able to do the **same** with any valid `module`. Doenst matter thirdparty or our-own. Of course, there are some js libraries still not modularized. I can only guess they will have some or the other problem while bundling. Any specific thirdparty library module you have in mind that has problem?